# Show that given p,there exists x such that d(px)=x and also y such that d(p^2y)=y

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$$
Show\,\,that\,\,given\,\,p, there\,\,exists\,\,x\,\,such\,\,that\,\,d\left( px \right) =x\,\,and\,\,also\,\,y\,\,such\,\,that\,\,d\left( p^2y \right) =y
$$
where d(x) denotes the number of divisors of x.

This is a question from *The art and craft of problem solving*

My attempt:p=2,x=4,p(2*4)=4. p=3,x=6,p(3*6)=6. p=4,x=9.p(4*9)=9. p=5,x=12

Can not find a pattern...Can not think of a way to create or trim it. Do I need to use some inversion formulas?

Comment: Is $p$ meant to be prime? Otherwise,  the second request is not sensible if we have proved that an $x$ exists for any $p$ (since $p^2$ is just any $p$).

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a prime greater than 3, then $d(12p)=12$.

If $p$ is a prime not equal to 3, then $d(9p^2)=9$. For $p=3$, $d(12.3^2)=12$.